# For 2 dynamically generated TD

Tags: javascript, css

Right now the following code generates two much white spaces between the two TDs.

How to set the first TD left aligned and 
the second TD left aligned to the first TD?

// nTR being the newly TR
nTR.setAttribute('style','td {padding: 10px}') has no effect.  How to go about it?

```
// creating row and creating all cells
// creates a table row
var newrow = document.createElement("tr");
newrow.setAttribute('style','td {padding: 10px}');

// cell 1
    var cell = document.createElement("td");            
    cell.colSpan = "2"; 
    // cell.setAttribute('style','padding: 10px');              
    var cellText = document.createElement('input');
    cellText.type = 'text';
    cellText.id = 'fLabel';
    cellText.name = 'fLabel';
    cellText.size = "20";
    cell.appendChild(cellText);
    newrow.appendChild(cell);       

// cell 2
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.colSpan = "3";
    var cellText = document.createElement('input');
    cellText.type = 'text';
    cellText.id = 'fValue';
    cellText.name = 'fValue';
    cellText.size = "80";
    cell.appendChild(cellText);
    newrow.appendChild(cell);

    // code to append the new TR to table
    // ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: i'm confused what you are asking. please post more details and all the code you have

Comment: ok, code added, thanks.

Comment: seems working to me, there's no space between the two TDs. see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/womyhqwb/)

Comment: well, the page is complex, it has tons of other stuff, tons of dynamically generated elements before and after.  thanks

Comment: ahe, never mind, solved. it's TD alignment with other TD issue, thanks anyway.